# testlink integration with mantis(interface:SOAP)

Tags: soap, mantis, testlink

i have installed testlink 1.9.16 and mantis bugtracker 2.3.1 on wamp server 3.0.6.

i tried to integrate mantis and teslink on soap interface . but i'm getting these errors:

**-in testlink events :** "SOAP Fault: (code: Client, string: looks like we got no XML document)"

**-in C:\wamp64\logs\php_error.log :**

```
[22-Apr-2017 13:06:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Server] Error Type: SYSTEM WARNING,
Error Description: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in C:\wamp64\www\mantis\api\soap\mc_api.php:668
Stack trace:

    #0 [internal function]: mc_error_handler(2, 'Cannot modify h...', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\m...', 84, Array)
    #1 C:\wamp64\www\mantis\api\soap\mantisconnect.php(84): SoapServer->handle()
    #2 {main}
      thrown in C:\wamp64\www\mantis\api\soap\mc_api.php on line 668
```

**this is my configuration for mantisbt in testlink:**

```
<!-- Template mantissoapInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>administrator</username>
<password>toor</password>
<uribase>http://localhost/mantis/</uribase>

<uriwsdl>http://localhost/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>http://localhost/mantis/view.php?id=</uriview>
<uricreate>http://localhost/mantis/</uricreate>
<!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->
<project>demo_bt</project>
<category>selenium</category>

</issuetracker>
```

Anybody have any idea about this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the comments in your configuration and check. Check my config please

```
<issuetracker>
<username>administrator</username>
<password>admin123</password>
<uribase>http://localhost/mantis/</uribase>
<uriwsdl>http://localhost/mantis/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>http://localhost/mantis/view.php?id=</uriview>
<uricreate>http://localhost/mantis/</uricreate>
<project>Testing</project>
<category>development</category>
<resolvedstatus>
<status><code>80</code><verbose>resolved</verbose></status>
<status><code>90</code><verbose>closed</verbose></status>
</resolvedstatus>
</issuetracker>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue. the problem was that i was using an api key which it belongs to the administrator of redmine, so i created a new project with new members and i used the api key of the manager of this new project and it's working ffine now .